# How to reproject manually created label positions?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I changed position to some features' labels and I activated the x,y position in the label properties.
I saved the layer in .shp and with another projection.
Once created a new project with that projection I loaded the .shp.
Now I can see only labels of those features I didn't move the label. So I think that labels' X,Y coordinates saved in the layer aren't reprojected

How could I have these coordinates reprojected?

Comment: Can you use postgres/postgis? Using only Qgis I think the method suggested from AndreJ is the only one.

Comment: Hi! I don't know Postgres and Postgis... that will be my next step in GIS learning

Answer (score 4):

Try this

1. Make sure your attribute table has a unique identifier per line
2. Save the layer with the label coordinates to a csv file
3. Load the csv with `Add delimited text` using the label coordinates as `X` and `Y` fields
4. Save the new layer as shapefile into the target projection
5. With the field calculator, add new columns of type `real` with the projected coordinates (Geometry -> `$x` and `$y` )
6. Save the changes and leave edit mode
7. Save the new layer as csv and add it to the canvas
8. Join your original layer with the latest CSV layer by the unique ID field
9. Save to a new shapefile, and style the labels to the projected coordinates

Comment: Hi! Thx for reply... Sorry, I'm embaracced... How do I do points 8?

Comment: In the properties of the original layer, you have a `join` tab. Click on the plus for a new connection, and select the latest CSV layer, then select the ID field in both layers.

Comment: After this join and having saved the .shp... Do I need to mantain both files to keep join?

Comment: The last shp should contain all you need. You can move it to another folder and open it in a new project if you doubt.

Comment: Ok... I think I'm doing some sort of error, cause I'm getting an all mixed-up file. I understood the logic behinde so I'll continue trying this way. Thx

Comment: Maybe you have no unique ID for every label, or it got lost. You can try the MMQGIS plugin to export the attribute table.

Comment: Oh My God! I don't know why, since my try now Whichever csv file I attempt to import Qgis add field named "field_22", "field_23" ecc... even if they doesn't exist in the csv. All points are aligned horizontally... I tried restart PC but nothing occur and I have this problem...

Comment: You might have to check for correct cr-lf setting and separator, and mark `First record has field names`.

Comment: I created a new project with general wgs84 (4326) I imported a csv file, checked for First record has field names", selected x and y field and at the end the wgs84 cr... but I have only an horizontal line of points.

Comment: I'm working on Win 7 64bit

Comment: I cleaned the registry, a rapid defragmentation and powered off PC unplugging from AC. Restared and now all works... so I think there's something with memory or cache bug with Qgis. I restart studying the case.